# Better performance from CASE statement or Function in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I have a set of tables that have the following structure repeated multiple times:

```
Sign|Value
    |1000
   -|1000
```

So there is a "sign" column followed by the "value" column...and both values are `varchar(..)`.  I am building tables from this base data and want to convert to a decimal using sign.

At the moment I have been doing the following:

```
CASE
    WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(s.PreviousPointBalanceSign)) = '-'
    THEN -1 * CAST(s.PreviousPointBalance AS decimal(14,2))
    ELSE  CAST(s.PreviousPointBalance AS decimal(14,2))
END AS PreviousPointBalance
```

But I would like to know if using a function to achieve this would give me better performance?

Comment: Why do the tables have this structure in the first place? As opposed to simply storing `-1000` as a `decimal(14,2)`?

Comment: If it is performance you are after, then store data in the appropriate data type. To answer your question though, you will get significantly better performance using a CASE expression over a scalar function. If you use an inline TVF instead of a scalar function, as described in [this article by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions), then the performance of your function and case expression will be exactly the same since the definition of the function is simply expanded out into the main query.

Comment: `CASE` statement is better performer than `SCALAR` function.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have absolutely no ####### idea!  But they do and I can't change them :(

Comment: positive values have a whitespace? empty string? any character but -?

Comment: @1010 Positive values are one from '', ' ' or '+', but never '-' or `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of function are you planning to use? Basically functions does not help with the performance. They simplify the code, they give you ability to re-use the code and so on. Plain SQL will always be better or the same. In your case the best solution would be to store the data in the proper way, however if it is not possible then try to do the same thing in different ways. For example:

```
    1) CASE WHEN Sign like '%-%';
    2) CASE WHEN LEN(Sign) > 0.
3) You can also avoid CASE at all: SELECT CAST(Value AS Decimal(14,2)) * ((-1 + (LEN(Sign)^1) * 2))
```

You can also use calculated persisted column to calculate the value when it is inserted.

UPD:

After small tests, optimizer shown absolutely the same plan for all of the ways:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
        value VARCHAR(3),
    [sign] VARCHAR(3)

);

DECLARE @a INT = 0;
WHILE (@a < 1000)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(100)), CASE WHEN @a%2 =0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END )
SET @a=@a+1;

END


SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(s.[sign])) = '-'
    THEN -1 * CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
    ELSE  CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
END AS PreviousPointBalance
FROM #test s

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN s.[sign] LIKE '%-%'
    THEN -1 * CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
    ELSE  CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
END AS PreviousPointBalance
FROM #test s

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN  LEN(s.sign) >0
    THEN -1 * CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
    ELSE  CAST(s.value AS decimal(14,2))
END AS PreviousPointBalance
FROM #test s

SELECT  CAST(Value AS Decimal(14,2)) * ((-1 + (LEN(Sign)^1) * 2)) AS PreviousPointBalance
FROM #test s
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the best choice would be to convert your two columns into one, but since that's not an option. I think your stuck. If you could alter your table and make [sign] char(1), you'll have 2 bytes less per row. Which is you have 25 million rows * 2 bytes = 50MB. So narrowing that should help at least a little bit.

As far as a function, I don't know if there is a faster way to do it. There is a simpler way though like so:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(RTRIM([sign]),value) AS DECIMAL(14,2)) AS PreviousPointBalance
FROM yourTable
```

You only need RTRIM() because SQL Server doesn't care about spaces around the varchar to be casted to decimal. If you were to alter your table to CHAR(1), you wouldn't even have to worry about RTRIM()

```
SELECT CAST('   -99  ' AS DECIMAL(14,2)) --works
SELECT CAST('-   99  ' AS DECIMAL(14,2)) --fails
```